# Как из localstorage воспроизвети код в textarea

Tags: javascript

Я использую ace.js. Создаю я свой онлайн редактор и у меня появилась одна проблема. Я хочу, чтобы когда я написал код в textarea и сохранил его (при сохранения код должен попадать в localstorage), при перезагрузки страницы показывался именно тот код, который я сохранял (то есть найти сохраненный код из localstorage).Этот код должен попасть в textarea.

```js
    var eh = ace.edit("htmlEditor");
 eh.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
 eh.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
 document.getElementById('htmlEditor').style.fontSize='15px';
 eh.getSession().on('change', function() {
  update();
})
function update() {
var res = document.getElementById('result').contentWindow.document;
res.open();
res.write(eh.getValue());
res.close();
}
update();
```

```css
#menu-code {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.save {
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#htmlEditor {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 43vh;
    width: 33.03%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf 8">
<title>Finance</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.3/ace.js"></script>
</head>
   
    <body>
      
 <div id="header-code">
                     <div id="menu-code">
                      <ul class="mnu-code">
                        <li class="save" onclick="saveFiles()"> Сохранить</li>
</div>
    </div>
<div id="htmlEditor"></div>
<div id="result-block">
<iframe id="result" frameborder="0"></iframe><div id="line4"></div></div>
</body>
    </html>
```

Помогите мне, пожалуйста.

Comment: код надо сохранять в файле.

Comment: @Roman C то есть

Comment: Какая ошибка у вас в консоли?

Comment: @ Roman C как надо написать код, чтобы сохранять написанный код в textarea в файл, а потом по перезагрузке страницы выводить его